# Sentence recognition

Tags: java, regex

I would like my Java program to take science text book questions such as,

How far can a cyclist travel in 4.0 h if his average speed is 11.5 km/h?

as a string and then I would like the program to recognize every number and unit mentioned in the question, e.g. in the example above it will be 4.0 h and 11.5 km/h.

Is it possible to use regex for this purpose?

Many thanks

Comment: It would handle a very limited set of sentences. You need a parser.

Comment: Or just download OpenWatson from Source Forge and turn it loose.

Comment: Are you interested in making the program "understand" the _meaning_ of each sentence (which is extremely difficult), or are you just interested in extracting all numbers and the unit immediately following each number? If it's the latter, and you're okay with getting a few false positives (such as a question beginning with "A 4th grader gets $5 from his parents" resulting in the number 4 with the unit "th"), then a regex should suffice.

Comment: @Aasmund - If he added a little processing afterwards to check the regex'd units against an enumeration of valid units he could eliminate the false positives.

Comment: Well yeah, I am interested to extract all numbers and the unit immediately following, and then have the program to calculate the missing variables. I think I am going to use regex then.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution :**
Here is a sample code in java that will match your needs :

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regexp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String units = "h|km/h";// Add more units separated by pipes here
        String test = "How far can a cyclist travel in 4.0 h if his average speed is 11.5 km/h?";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?\\s*(?:" + Matcher.quoteReplacement(units) + ")",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(test);

        System.out.println("Numbers and units recognized: ");
        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

It will output :

```
Numbers and units recognized: 
4.0 h
11.5 km/h
```

**Details :**
I assume a number has the **following form** :
   *one or more digits(0-9) optionally followed by a dot and one more digits(0-9)*

You can add more units as needed in the pipe separated list ***units*** variable